# SQL Server how do I reduce the amount of memory granted by stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Running sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks shows me the following:

[image]

There's a lot of process stuck on CXPACKET. Googling this issue indicated that this has something to do with parallel execution of the queries and that I have to mess around with MAXDOP settings, but the resource description for all of the processes make little sense:

```
exchangeEvent id=Pipe271035100 WaitType=e_waitPipeGetRow nodeId=5
```

Waittype showing e_waitPipeGetRow seems to indicate that it has something to do with either deadlock or massive amount of queries being locked, but I might be wrong.

My question is, how do I go about troubleshooting this issue? I'm not even sure where to look.

Edit:

Since the posting of this question, the below issue went away all of a sudden for a while. Today though, same issue occurred and here's what I found with sys.dm_exec_requests:

[image]

There's several PROCID showing lots of cxpacket. Here's an example of one of them:
123 0   2015-02-10 16:12:21.617 suspended   SELECT  0x0300070048642C323B8DB30036A400000100000000000000  1304    11288   0x0500070048642C3240210C14030000000000000000000000  7   5   59676462-0CB3-4FB8-96FC-530B3892578D    0   RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE  248137  RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE      0   1   1583321 0x  0   0   0   248138  8   0x000000000460A748  0   0   0   -1  한국어 ymd 7   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   2   -1  0   0   0   4   0   0   1   0x941A9D1F032CAA8A  0x1CCA978D548EB09E

Wait type showing RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE seems to indicate that the threads are in contention for resources while running the query in parallel, but I'm not sure. How do I troubleshoot this?

Edit2:

Ah now I'm finally beginning to understand the core issue

Running sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants showed me pretty surprising info:

[image]

Several processes are being granted a huge amount of memory (3 Gigs from above picture). In bad cases, several processes start requesting that amount of memory, leading to **resource contention**. This is what caused all of the RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE wait types.

Digging deeper, I've found that this occurs when a particular stored procedure is repeatedly called. We will eventually fix the underlying SQL problems in it. I believe it has something to do with parameter sniffing but to mitigate the resource contention issue immediately, I've tried taking the following measures:

First, I ran DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear the plan cache. This didn't reduce the amount of memory requested.

Then I tried to alter the procedure with OPTION RECOMPILE. This didn't do anything either.

So I'm pretty lost on where to go about this. How do I make the SP request for less memory?

Comment: While this is happening, look in sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks for threads associated with these sessions that *aren't* showing CXPACKET waits - that will usually tell you what is causing this. Next, do you realize you're using SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM, and that is no longer supported? There may be fixes for the issue you're experiencing in the service packs that have been released...

Comment: @JamesZ this is a common scenario where the executing session_id is the same as the blocking session id, so it looks like it's blocking itself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. This isn't supported by Microsoft anymore? Anyways, I'll try running sys.dm_exec_requests as well and see what I get.

Comment: A good article on CXPacket waits

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/

Comment: [According to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=sql) mainstream support for 2008 R2 RTM ended on 7/8/2014. However if you update to Service Pack 3 that is still under standard support.

Comment: RTM is no longer supported, no. Get the most recent service pack.

Comment: @AaronBertrand In dm_os_waiting_tasks and dm_exec_requests, how do I know what sessions these problematic threads are associated with? What column should I be looking at?

Comment: Thinking laterally, can you add more RAM to the production machine while you investigate the root cause? It's pretty cheap these days.

Comment: @KyleHale It's already on 24 Gigs of RAM, although we're seriously considering about doubling the ram

Comment: @Scott: SP3 for 2008 R2 would not come under standard support it would come under extended support. Mainstream support of 2008 r2 ended previous year I guess

Comment: There are couple of things into picture here CXPACKET waits , resource semaphore waits and this makes me belive that something is wrong with statistics or query optimizer is not able to somehow make correct estimate. You must apply SP3 ASAP and then revert with status of the issue

Comment: If it was possible to limit the amount of memory available to a stored procedure and you did so, would this really fix the problem? I think not and it would only cause more problems. Ultimately the issue is with the underlying stored procedure(s) and/or underlying data structures (incorrect data types, missing indexes etc.)

Comment: Can you please post the execution plan? It is _possible_ that maybe a new index (even if only temporary until the "underlying SQL problems are fixed") might help, depending on what's going on. Hard to say without knowing more about what is actually happening in the system. Right now we are just being told of the effect.

Comment: I'm seconding the request for the execution plan. I recently ran into this same problem (a query executing many times in parallel asking for ridiculous amounts of memory) and the problem turned out to be that SQL Server severely overestimated the amount of memory needed, because my table had a ton of `VARCHAR` fields that were much wider than necessary. The optimizer simply multiplied the estimated number of rows by the expected row size, and voila, a way too big memory claim was the result. I solved it by actually changing the result set (a lot of fields were actually unnecessary).

Answer (score 6):

If you are running Enterprise Edition of SQL Server you can set the maximum memory that will be allocated to a single query as a percentage of the available server memory using:

```
ALTER WORKLOAD GROUP [DEFAULT] WITH (REQUEST_MAX_MEMORY_GRANT_PERCENT = 25)
GO
-- RECONFIGURE to make the setting take effect
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

25% is the default value, reducing this may cause as many problems as it solves though. If you can isolate the connections executing the problem queries it is possible to configure separate limits for those connections see:

[Sql Server Resource Governor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx)

Resource Governor is a enterprise only feature, I understand all editions use the default workload group for standard resource allocation though. I would been interested if anyone knows if reconfiguring the default workload group works on  non-Enterprise instances?

To find help fine the cause of your problem:

If you have narrowed the issue down to a problem stored procedure the execution plan can tell you what operators are causing the large memory grants. In SSMS you need to open the operator properties to see all the memory grant information.

The root node in the execution plan will have information about the memory grant for the query.

Operators that are allocated working memory will have a Memory Fraction property which specifies the fraction of the queries total memory grant the operator is excepted to use.

You are looking for operators that have a memory fraction close to 1, Hash Match and Sort operators are a good place to start looking.

If you can locate the problem area altering the query or indexing to eliminate the operation or reduce the estimated number of rows involved should reduce the memory grant requested.

Answer (score 1):

This wait type is encountered when a query executes a parallel plan and some of the threads finish before others. The threads that are waiting for the others to finish display this wait type. As for the wait description, my take on it is that it's a way to describe the fact that that thread is waiting for its results to be consumed. So, in short, there's not much to worry about here.

One thing to look at though is: why are the threads getting such uneven work loads? An easy way to see how many rows are being consumed by each operator in an execution plan is with the Plan Explorer tool from SQL Sentry. My guess is that you'll see a skew. In my experience, this is usually caused by inaccurate statistics.

Comment: Problem is, when this occurs, all of the queries to DB is runs noticeably slow.

Answer (score 0):

There are only few reasons for SQL server to ask that amount of memory, assuming it isn't a bug (since it worked fine before) it must be an non optimal query plan. The quick fix would be updating the statistics and rebuilding indexes.

If that doesn't help I'm afraid you'll need to do at least a bit of debugging. Knowing which query is causing your head age helps a lot. Putting `OPTION(RECOMPILE, FORCE ORDER)` hints on the query helps in a lot cases.

The following statement may also help you dialing into the problematic query. It list all queries from the plan cache along with the number of times execution and average execution time. Beware, it's an heavy statement, disabling fetching the query plan will remediate that.

```
SELECT [qh] .*, [qp] .query_plan
FROM (SELECT [cp]. [objtype]
          , [Query Hash] = [qs2].[query_hash]
          , [Query Plan Hash] = [qs2].[query_plan_hash]
          , [Total MB] = SUM ( [cp].[size_in_bytes] ) /
               1024.00 / 1024.00
          , [Avg CPU Time]
               = SUM ([qs2] .[total_worker_time]) /
                    SUM ( [qs2].[execution_count] )   
          , [Execution Total]
               = SUM ([qs2] .[execution_count])
          , [Total Cost]
               = SUM ([qs2] .[total_worker_time])
          , [Example Statement Text]
               = MIN ([qs2] .[statement_text])
          , [plan_handle] = MIN ( [qs2].[plan_handle] )
          , [statement_start_offset] =
               MIN ( [qs2].[statement_start_offset] )
     FROM (SELECT [qs].*,
               SUBSTRING ( [st].[text] ,
                    ([qs]. [statement_start_offset] / 2) + 1,
               ((CASE [statement_end_offset] WHEN -1 THEN
                    DATALENGTH ( [st].[text] )
                    ELSE [qs] .[statement_end_offset] END -
                         [qs].[statement_start_offset] ) / 2) + 1)
                         AS [statement_text]
               FROM [sys] .[dm_exec_query_stats] AS [qs]
                    CROSS APPLY [sys]. [dm_exec_sql_text]
                         ([qs]. [sql_handle]) AS [st]) AS [qs2]
               INNER JOIN [sys]. [dm_exec_cached_plans] AS [cp]
                    ON [qs2] .[plan_handle] = [cp] .[plan_handle]
               GROUP BY [cp]. [objtype], [qs2].[query_hash] ,
                    [qs2].[query_plan_hash] ) AS [qh]
CROSS APPLY [sys]. [dm_exec_query_plan]
                         ([qh]. [plan_handle]) AS [qp]
-- For the demo, use the ORDER BY [Example Statement Text]
ORDER BY [Example Statement Text]
-- For the real-world, use the following order by:
-- ORDER BY [qh].[Total Cost] DESC
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **Resource Governor** shipped with SQL Server for limiting or sparing resources for SQL tasks

Answer (score -7):

At the first step do the following and repeat your testing

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options' ,1
reconfigure
go

sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism',1
reconfigure
go

sp_configure 'show advanced options' ,0
reconfigure
go
```

After this configuration, carry on your testing and see if the problem is solved.